# How to Use corrplot with method="number" and Drop Leading Zero?

Tags: r, r-corrplot

How does one plot a correlation matrix in R using the package corrplot and drop the leading zero when using 'method="number"'?

For example, if a correlation is '0.78', I would like it to display '.78' or '78' in order to save space.

Regards,
Scott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an example from the `corrplot` documentation:

```
data(mtcars)
M <- cor(mtcars)

corrplot(round(100*M), method="number", col="black", cl.pos="n",is.corr=F)
```

The key here is that we actually are plotting a correlation matrix, but we're multiplying by 100 and rounding, so we have to set `is.corr=F`.

[image]

Comment: how to still display the leading dot "." ?

Comment: @florian I'm not aware of an easy way to do this, since `corrplot()` needs a numeric argument.